# Redemption - LogonHostedExchangeMailbox error

Tags: c#, outlook-redemption

Trying to login to an Office 365 Mailbox and list the contents.

I have the latest version of outlook (64 bit) installed via Office 365

[image]

I am getting this error

> Error in IMAPISession::OpenEntry: MAPI_E_UNKNOWN_FLAGS

Here is what redemption says are my versions

[image]

```
    var codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
    var uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
    var path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
    path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

     RedemptionLoader.DllLocation32Bit = string.Concat(path, @"\Redemption.dll");
    RedemptionLoader.DllLocation64Bit = string.Concat(path, @"\Redemption64.dll");

    var session = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();


    session.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox("MyUser@MyDomain.com", "MyUser@MyDomain.com", "MyPW");       

    if (session.LoggedOn)
    {
        RDOFolder contactsFolder;

        contactsFolder = session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox); // getting error at this line         

        var i = contactsFolder.Folders.Count;

        var tt = contactsFolder.Items.Count;

        foreach (var item in contactsFolder.Folders)
        {
            var obj = (RDOFolder2) item;
            var name = obj.AddressBookName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I sent thy debug version of Redemption to you.

Comment: Emailed you the log.. thanks